# How to Open Existing Java Project Given Entire Source Files

Tags: java, eclipse, blackberry, blackberry-simulator

I'm having some trouble opening an existing blackberry eclipse project I have to work on. The project has been left for me in a folder which includes subfolders such as bin, deliverables, src and res. How do I go about opening this? I've tried "import existing projects into workspace" and selecting that folder - which loads the project on the left hand banner of eclipse but with a red explanation mark on the icon. When I right click the project and select "run as blackberry simulator" nothing happens. I have consulted these articles:

[Opening an existing Java project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825288/opening-an-existing-java-project)
[open existing java project in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3095996/open-existing-java-project-in-eclipse)

but I seem to have been given the entire project structure instead of just the .jar file so I'm not sure if these are the steps to follow. I have tried the followed

1. File -> Import -> Existing Project into Workspace
2. Browse for that directory.

which loads the project but gives the red exclamation mark on the project.My other project which is loaded on the left banner does not have the exclamation mark on the project icon and can also be right clicked and run as a blackberry simulator. I am using the blackberry eclipse plugin.

Thanks for any help!

---

EDIT

Under Problems view: "The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved" and "unbound classpath container: 'JRE System Library [BlackBerry JRE 6.0.0] in project 'MyProject'"

Original work had been done by an ADMIN user who had copied the project to the server. The original file would have come from

```
C:\Users\ADMIN\Documents\Workspace\PROJECTNAME\deliverables\Standard\6.0.0
```

although I copied it from the server location. The place where I copied it is on my local machine at

```
C:\Users\MYNAME\Documents\workspace\PROJECTNAME\deliverables\Standard\6.0.0
```

That path is a jar file I found. There is also one in ..\Standard\7.0.0. A user provided feedback below to right click on resolve but I am confused as how I can right click on resolve and provide the correct path . I am not sure if this is is the correct .jar file to be honest I am not too sure on how blackberry directories work in this case. I am following this article

http://agile.csc.ncsu.edu/SEMaterials/tutorials/import_export/

Comment: Red exclamation mark signals an error. What is the error signaled?

Comment: Under Problems view: "The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved" and "unbound classpath container: 'JRE System Library [BlackBerry JRE 6.0.0] in project 'MyProject'"

Comment: There you go. You didn't add the Blackberry library to eclipse classpath

Comment: Download the BlackBerry library ..

Comment: I am using the blackberry plugin for eclipse, it should be in there. The problem is I am moving one project from one computer to another computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No reinstall was necessary and it turns out that I was using the JRE 7.0.0 and needed 6.0.0.  I installed the JRE from the BB Java plug-in update site and after an Eclipse restart I was able to open the project. The link to use with Eclipse if anyone else has a similar issue is: http://www.blackberry.com/go/eclipseUpdate/3.6/java

Answer (score 1):

Follow this comprehensive guide on installing Blackberry plugin into eclipse:

http://www.blackberryforums.com/developer-forum/138210-setup-up-eclipse-blackberry-development.html

Comment: I am already using blackberry eclipse plugin, should have mentioned that - my mistake

Comment: @user1152440 you are using it incorrectly. Reinstall it by following the guide and that is on the NEW computer where you are trying to run it

Comment: I am using this: http://us.blackberry.com/developers/javaappdev/javaplugin.jsp . This is also what the other computer that originally had the code was also using.

Comment: Do you recommend a reinstall of both?

Comment: @user1152440 No, just reinstall where you are using it

Answer (score 0):

The Red exclamation mark in Eclipse usually signals class-path problems (i.e. some libs are missing or they are not configured correctly ). Use the Markers view to get more details about the errors.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have build path issues. It is normal since the other developer might have referred to libraries using absolute paths on his machine which need not necessarily exist in the same location on yours.

Open the `Problems` view and see what you can resolve.

Comment: "The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved" and "unbound classpath container: 'JRE System Library [BlackBerry JRE 6.0.0] in project 'MyProject'"

Answer (score 0):

**Well Well Well**, the problem is because the path for the jar files are INCORRECT in eclipse.

**E.g** You earlier did work in Eclipse at machine A. There you had your library files at `D:/MyJarFiles/`. Now you copied that folder in Pen Drive and copied in you machine B & exported in eclipse. Now just take mouse over your library/jar files. You will see the path that was defined in the machine A (i.e. `D:/MyJarFiles/`). In machine B, you might have jar files at some other path (like say `D:/JarFiles/`). As Eclipse can't find path `D:/MyJarFiles/` in machine B, it throws error. As jar files are not included, you will get error in your Java file (as your `import` is not working)..

**How to solve**

Just create `D:/MyJarFiles/` and put jar files there 
OR
Right Click on jar file and click resolve and provide correct path. I believe you are done with one, all jar files will detect new location.

Good Luck!!!

Comment: Hey that's exactly what the situation is. Original work had been done by an ADMIN user who copied the project to the server. The original file would have come from C:\Users\ADMIN\Documents\Workspace\PROJECTNAME\deliverables\Standard\6.0.0 although I copied it from the server. The place where I copied it is C:\Users\MYNAME\Documents\workspace\PROJECTNAME\deliverables\Standard\6.0.0. That path is the only one jar file I found. I'm a little confused as how I can right click on resolve and provide the correct path (this isn't a windows directory right click right?).

Comment: can you send me screen shot of your IDE? I will tell you then what to do... my email id is in my profile...